# Excel vba to copy existing worksheet based on horizontal list

Tags: vba, excel

First things first - I'm a complete vba novice, and the code I've put together was total trial and error.

I'm trying to create a code which will allow me to create copies of an existing worksheet (entitled "Template") based upon a horizontal list of departmental names in Row 6 of the "Statistics" worksheet (starting in cell F6).  For any new departments needed to be included in the document, the user can simply add a new title into the next cell (G6, H6 etc), press the button to run the vba and a new worksheet will appear with the new title as the worksheet title.

The reason I need it to do this is that I am using the INDIRECT function to calculate percentages based on departmental data, and I don't want to rely on whoever uses the workbook in the future knowing how to modify something in Excel (i.e. copying and pasting an existing worksheet, renaming it and then updating the list appropriately).

The code I've put together is this:

```
Sub New_worksheet()

Dim j As Integer
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("Template")
Set sh = Sheets("Statistics")
Set Rng = Cells(6, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft)

Application.ScreenUpdating = 0

For j = 5 To Rng.Column
Sheets("Template").Copy Before:=sh
ActiveSheet.Name = sh.Range("6" & j).Value
Next j

End Sub
```

But I get a problem with the *ActiveSheet.Name = sh.Range("6" & j).Value* part.  I think I've sorted out the problems in the rest of the code, but since it keeps having to debug, I'm not sure.

Can anyone help, please?!!

Comment: Quick use of the macro recorder would tell you that `Range` needs to be in the form of column then row, e.g. `Range("A1")`. You could use `Cells` instead of `Range` and keep your existing formulation.

Answer (score 0):

For range need to define column then row. You can use cells instead of range.
`ActiveSheet.Name = sh.Cells(6, j).Value`